# How to view log file on service startup?

Tags: windows, alfresco, prompt

Is it possible to view the log files when starting alfresco services on windows (prompt), like the tail -f on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is two approaches to achieve that:

1. Start Alfresco tomcat as a service, and have a 3rd party software like [mtail](http://ophilipp.free.fr/op_tail.htm)* and tail the `<alfresco-path>\alfresco.log`
2. Stop tomcat service from `msc.exe`, tweak `setenv.bat` inside `<path-to-alfresco-dir>\tomcat\bin\setenv.bat` to give sufficient memory to the JVM, and then run `<path-to-alfresco-dir>\tomcat\bin\startup.bat` inside a `cmd` console

---

* [Here](http://stackify.com/11-ways-to-tail-a-log-file-on-windows-unix/)  is a [list](http://stackify.com/11-ways-to-tail-a-log-file-on-windows-unix/) of alternative tools / methods.